# Loading kernel every time I turn on my laptop

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

Yesterday I got an update package from ubuntu, during installation the laptop completely shut down. After that I have to manually load my kernel first with these commands:

'''
set prefix=(hd1,gpt5)/boot/grub
set root=(hd1,gpt5)
insmod normal
normal
'''

After that it goes okay, but I feel really uncomfortable with having to do that and was wondering if there is a fix for that (I was not able to locate any online)

Comment: Have you tried to run `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: Yes, it did not work

Comment: Add that to your **/boot/grub/grub.cfg** file.

Comment: Could you provide more details? I am just a user of Ubuntu and apparently your advice was beyond my skills